# List<T> exposed as IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, generics, .net

I understand the hierarchy between the two and know how to convert between them, but is there anything fundamentally wrong with declaring a list like this?

```
IEnumerable<int> _bookmarkedDeals = new List<int>();
```

I don't need to change the list at any point, its either created or recreated as a whole.

As an alternative, possibly this

```
IEnumerable<int> _bookmarkedDeals = Enumerable.Empty<int>();
```

Comment: This is valid code, but if your implementation is immutable, why not just use a simple array? `IEnumerable<int> _bookmarkedDeals = new int[x]` as List has some overhead with it that you won't be using

Comment: What are you doing with the _bookmarkedDeals that requires it to be empty?

Comment: @James My guess is that the variable will, rather than being modified to add items to the list, just have another sequence assigned to it directly.  If that doesn't happen, whatever wrapper exposes it publicly should return an empty sequence (rather than null).  At least, that's my theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in this case, `_bookmarkedDeals` will be empty so the declaration is somewhat useless. That being said, nothing wrong with treating a List as an IEnumerable.

Comment: Well, it's wrong if you end up needing functionality provided by `List` and not by `IEnumerable`.  In those cases you either won't be able to do what you need, you'll be casting it in which case you would have been better off leaving the variable as a `List`, or you end up doing something like calling `ToList` which is just inefficient.

Comment: Precisely. If you treat it as an IEnumerable, it's fine. If you need the List functionality, it is not.

Answer (score 1):

(Unlike all answers here..) **Yes**. There is something very wrong with this declaration. You won't be able to use any of `List<T>` features without casting all the time back to list.

It's a **good** practice to return this type from your method if no list operations will be performed later on. But while you're in the same method - you're just making your life harder and less performant (because of the casts).

Comment: "all answers here" is too much generalization: specifically, the first part of my answer is precisely about that difference.

Comment: You are correct. I'm just trying to emphasize the point that it **is** bad practice to use it this way..

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no problem with your declaration, although some people do like to declare the variable type precisely without any abstractization.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with that declaration but unless you have any specific restriction, `IList<int>` is a more appropiated interface for a list.

Comment: Why cast it from `List` to `IList`.  it is still more restrictive, and unless you are assigning other objects that aren't a `List` to that variable you don't gain anything.

Comment: @Sevy: `IList<T>` it is more restrictive but less restrictive than `IEnumerable<T>`. I assumed that he's exposing that object to the external world and that's why he uses an interface.

Comment: Well, it's a field, so I *really* hope he's not exposing it to the entire world.  If there is a method or property that wraps it and exposes it, then that's the place to use an interface to restrict what can be done externally.  The private field is usually best left with the most derived type.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong.

If you never change the list in any way you could possibly use an array - it is slightly lighter than a list.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing fundamentally wrong with it, but why would you want to slice off some of the functionality that List provides (that IEnumerable doesn't)?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with that, that's good design.
Have a read of [Arrays Considered Somewhat Harmful](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/22/arrays-considered-somewhat-harmful.aspx).
Fabulous read about selecting the right interface.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is nothing wrong with it.

If this is a local variable, I see no benefit over just using `var` to create a variable of type `List<int>`. If you are just enumerating, it does no harm at all though. If it is a field, perhaps event publicly exposed, it can be very sensible not to expose it as a `List<int>` or `IList<int>` to keep the free choice of concrete type.

Answer (score 0):

There is no syntax problem but I don't see how it could be useful. If you don't insert any item in this row, this list is going to stay always empty unless you cast it back to `List<int>`, so why you want to declare it as `IEnumerable<int>`?